# Creating a playlist with multiple unique video stream links for internet streaming

Tags: playlist

Is it possible to create a playlist (eg. hls/dash) which will contain multiple video, (not different quality of the same video)
For example :

```
example.com/video1.mkv
example.com/Video2.mkv
example3.com/VideoN.mkv
```

These are unique videos, I want to have a playlist that can be played by player like VLC
So how do I do it? I tried creating `m3u` list but vlc sees it as if it is a single video and plays the first video only